# Splash Screen Mobile

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, splash-screen

I'm trying to set Splash Screen in my app developed with Cordova but I am not able, I am following the documentation[available on the official website](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/config_ref/images.html#link-2) does not work however, my doubts are as follows:

The `config.xml` file that must change is the first which is inside the project folder?

The documentation they pass this code `<splash src="res/screen/android/splash-port-hdpi.png" density="port-hdpi"/>`The path within the src can point to the 'src="www/img/splash"'>

Answer (score 0):

Easier and better way,

Use this.
https://github.com/AlexDisler/cordova-icon

Comment: I installed the plugin however when I give the `cordova-splash` command it is not recognized:  `cordova-splash is not recognized as an internal command or external, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: Have you followed all of the setup mentioned in that link ? You need to have imagemagick installed as well. Instructions are in that link

Comment: For all of you having the same problem like @ViniciusVAz where the cordova-splash plugin "is not recognized as internal command [...]":
Try installing it as global package: "npm install cordova-splash -g"
Helped for me!